# Find string using regex and regular expressions

Tags: c#, regex

I have this text, and I try to print `a1` and `a2`

```
<a href="a1" title="t1"> k1 </a>
<a href="a2" title="t2"> k2 </a>
```

Here is my attempt:

```
string html =  "<a href=\"a1\" title=\"t1\"> k1 </a>";
       html += "<a href=\"a2\" title=\"t2\"> k2 </a>";

 //here is how I think my logic expression should work:
 //<a href=" [something that is not quote, 0 or more times] " [anything] </a>
Regex regex = new Regex("<a href=\"([^\"]*)\".*</a>");
foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(html)
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1]);
```

Why does this only print `a1`? I am pretty sure I am doing it right. What am I missing ?

Comment: I don't code in c# but I think the `.*` should be `.*?` so it is non-greedy. Currently you'll go to the last `</a>`.

Comment: Wahoo I solved a c#, kinda..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular expression `.*` is consuming all characters upto the second `</a>`. What you need is lazy consumption with `.*?` so that it only consumes all characters up to the first `</a>`:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("<a href=\"([^\"]*)\".*?</a>");
```

Meanwhile,
[Why it's not possible to use regex to parse HTML/XML: a formal explanation in layman's terms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la)

Comment: this way, `("<a href=\"(.*?)\".*?</a>")` works too and its cleaner syntax-wise. I didn't know about the `?` symbol